# Getting user input from a PHP form and pasting into csv file

Tags: php, forms, csv, web-applications, spreadsheet

I have a number of php forms and a csv file to store the everything in. The csv file already contains existing data. I need to do the following:
When the submit button is pressed open the csv file and check if a specific field is empty (reference number just a way to link the forms together since each one is completed by a different person).
If it is paste the first field
Then move on to the next and so on and so on
Then when the submit is pressed on the other form check to find the reference number that matches and paste the values in each cell.
The row will remain the same but columns for each are specific to each form eg i have B E and F for form 1 A D G for form 2 and so on.

Can anyone give me an example of how this could be done? 
Thanks

```
    <html>
    <head><title>Network Design Request</title></head>
    <title>Design Request</title>     

      <form action="exec-data.php" method="POST">
      <fieldset align="left">
     <legend>Executive Sponsor Form</legend>
      <p><i>To be completed by the executive sponsor</i></p>
      <table>
    <tr>
    <td>Refrence Number:</td>
    <td><?php $Ref = new DateTime();
    echo $Ref->format('U') . "\n";
    ?>
    </td></tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="SNAME" size="40" /></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
       <td>Position:</td><td><input type="text" name="SPOSITION" size="40" /></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
       <td>Telephone Number:</td><td><input type="text" name="SNUMBER" size="40" maxlength="11" /></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
       <td>Email Address:</td><td><input type="email" name="SEMAIL" size="40" /></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
       <td>Budget Available:</td><td><input type="checkbox" /><input type="text" name="BUDGET" size="37" maxlength="6" placeholder="2014 budget submission code" /></td>
      </tr>

 <tr>
   <td>Aligned to which<br>priority:</td><td><input type="text" name="PRIORITIES" size="40" /></td>
  </tr>

  </form>
```

This is one of the forms and the code I have so far is:

```
    <?php

$inputFileType = 'csv';
$inputFileName = '\Documents\Network Design Project\Notepad++ndr_db.csv';
$sheetname = '2015 Jan';
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly($sheetname);
$objReader = $objReader->load($inputFileName);

$Refrow = 1
$Refcol = 2

foreach ($data as $Refrow){
    if ($Refrow is_null){$Refrow++}
    else ($_POST['$Ref'] )
}

$Exec_col = 5
$Exec_row = 1
foreach ($data as $Exec_row){
    if ($Exec_row is_null){$Exec_row++}
    else ($_POST['SNAME'] )
}

?>
```

Comment: This site is not a code-writing service. Show what you've done so far, and explain the problem you're having with your existing code.

Answer (score 0):

You should use fputcsv.
read manual from php.net

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

Comment: but that uses arrays and enters data row by row doesn't it? Is there a syntax to tell it paste in column B ignore C D and paste in E and F and so on?